# Everytime i exit my wb my frozen rows resets. wrok around possible?

Tags: excel

I have a large vertical table that I manipulate on an daily basis.  Every time I open the workbook I have to freeze the top panes. I use dual monitors so I usually have two windows open, if that matters.

Is there a way I can permanently freeze the top panes?

Comment: I suggest you do the Macro Recorder of you freezing the panes and then review your code and include it in the Workbook Open event so it runs as soon as you open it. If you have issues working with your code include it here and we will gladly help you. Regards,

Comment: Also if I'm not mistaken the frozen panes should be a property of a worksheet that is saved once you save the file. Any reason why the file is not saving that property once you change it?

Comment: That's a great idea why didn't i think of that.

Comment: and thanks nbayly, i used your comment to do a little more research, i guess it has to do with which window i used to freeze the panes.

Answer (score 0):

HAHA figured it out!

```
Sub FreezePane()

Dim excApp As Excel.Application
Set excApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Sheets("Inventory").Activate
excApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select
excApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

Sheets("Calculations").Activate
excApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Select
excApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

Sheets("WDCap").Activate
excApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C15").Select
excApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

Sheets("InjCap").Activate
excApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C15").Select
excApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

Sheets("Incremental P&L").Activate
excApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Select
excApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

Sheets("Dashboard").Activate

End Sub
```